# Maven package not grouping dependencies together

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm using the [ms-data-core-api](https://github.com/PRIDE-Utilities/ms-data-core-api/) library for a project. So I made a few tweaks around, recompiled it using `mvn package` which gave me a different .jar file, and installed it using `mvn install:install-file` so I could use it in my project's `pom` file. So far, so good. However, when I tried to use it on my project, I got some `cannot be resolved` issues.

By unpacking the [2.0.5 release jar](https://github.com/PRIDE-Utilities/ms-data-core-api/releases), which correctly works however doesn't have my modifications, I realized that it has all the dependencies inside of it, although mine doesn't (it has only the compiled library).

I'm not experienced with Maven, so what I did is:

1. extracted the working `2.0.5` jar content, containing all files
2. copied this content to my `2.0.6` build folder (created with `mvn instal:install-file`)
3. replaced the only the `ms-data-core-api` part with my compiled binaries
4. reassembled it with `jar cf myJar.jar tweaked-2.0.5-folder`.

It still doesn't work, giving me the same `cannot be resolved` error on the classes that I need.

By unpacking the latest jar created in step 4, I realized that it has all the `2.0.5` content enclosed in a folder (with the same name as `tweaked-2.0.5-folder`.

Am I missing something obvious here? Am I packaging back to `jar` wrongly? Or maybe is there a correct way to `mvn package` the library so that it builds all the dependencies together?

Comment: First building of a project is simply done by `mvn install` no need to do `mvn install:install-file` (If you need to do so something is wrong)..Furthermore the project has a CI build which is failed at the moment...Apart from that the project is doing many Maven releated things wrong...but this is a different story...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a correct way to do it. I suggest here 2 options

1. You should run `mvn install` instead of `mvn install:install-file`. It will maintain the `pom.xml` of ms-data-core-api in your PC's Maven repo `.m2`, and when your project refers to ms-data-core-api, your project will know all of its dependencies (transitive dependencies)
2. If you still want to make a fat Jar file which contains all dependencies, you can use the Maven Assembly Plugin. As I see from [this `pom.xml`](https://github.com/PRIDE-Utilities/ms-data-core-api/blob/master/pom.xml), they already had `<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>`.
   Instead of `mvn package`, you need to run: `mvn clean assembly:single`

Comment: By doing only `mvn install`, I get multiple `java.io.FileNotFoundException` (such as log4j, for example). I guess that's not what was supposed to happen, right? Thats weird...

Comment: It's weird. If you can do `mvn package`, then `mvn install` should be successful. Could you run `mvn package` without any error?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I guess I expressed myself wrongly: mvn install works correctly. The `FileNotFoundException` errors happen when I try to run the project using my compiled version.

Comment: Delete ms-data-core-api folder inside `.m2` folder (something like `uk/ac/ebi/pride/utilities/ms-data-core-api`, then run `mvn install` again. Checking the version installed in `.m2` and the version you use in your project's pom file. Also remember when you using Java IDE like Eclipse, you need to force Update project when dependencies change `Right-click on your project(s) --> Maven --> Update Project...`

Comment: I did it, and when I start debugging my project, I start getting the same exceptions (java.io.FileNotFoundException: `home/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar`). I guess I'll try to go with the fat jar and see what happens.

Comment: It's weird also. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7 should never be found from `../edu/ucar/netcdf4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118727/discussion-between-rocherlee-and-user2018675).